# Proof that conjugate subgroup has the same order as the subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that $|xHx^{-1}|=|H|$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $x\in G$.
I know how to prove that for each element in $H$, $|xhx^{-1}|=|h|$, but I'm not sure how to extend that to the whole subgroup.

Comment: Note that conjugation is a (self-) group action, so $\varphi_x(g) = x g x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism, so is either injective, so an isomorphism, or not.  You need to argue that "or not" doesn't happen.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to find a bijection between $H$ and $xHx^{-1}$. As drhab suggested the most natural one is: $$ f : H \rightarrow xHx^{-1} \mbox{ with } f(h)=xhx^{-1} \mbox{, where } h \in H $$

It is easy to see $f$ is injective since $ f(h_1) = f(h_2) $ implies $xh_1x^{-1}=xh_2x^{-1}$ and thus $h_1 = h_2$.

It is also easy to see that $f$ is surjective since for any $xhx^{-1} \in xHx^{-1}$ we have $xhx^{-1}=f(h)$ for $ h \in H$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

For any fixed $x$ the map $H\to xHx^{-1}$ prescribed by $h\mapsto xhx^{-1}$  is invertible (so is bijective).